# Nuxtjs not fetch data in product enviroment

Tags: nuxt.js

I build app by Nuxtjs.
I use fetch hook to call api, it's ok when run in local, but on product it show blank page, no data, no error show on console. Can you tell me how to fix it.

```html
<template>
  <div class="demo">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
------
<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
      post: {},
    }
  },

async fetch() {
    let slug = this.$route.params.slug
    this.post = await this.$axios.$get(`/posts/${slug}`)
  },
</script>
```

Comment: Does it work if you build/generate the project locally for production?

Comment: I had the same problem & when I build locally for production, it still  show blank components